# value of type 'Double?' has no member 'multiplied'

Tags: swift

After migrating to Swift 5, I'm getting this error in 3rd party code. What does it mean and how do I resolve?

```
/**
The timer's execution interval, in seconds.
*/
public let interval: Double!

/**
 *Starts the timer.
 * parameter now:     true, if the timer should fire immediately.
 */
open func start(_ now: Bool) {
    validate()
    if OSAtomicCompareAndSwap32Barrier(State.paused, State.running, 
        &running) {
        timer.scheduleRepeating(deadline: startTime(interval, now: 
        now), interval: 
        DispatchTimeInterval.nanoseconds(Int(interval.multiplied(by: 
        Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))))) // Swift Compiler Error here
        timer.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `interval` declared? Show that.

Comment: And where are you getting a `multiplied(by:)` method from?

Comment: search that 3rd party for `multiplied(by:` there may be an extension method for double that there a problem in accessing `open` / `public` problem

Comment: Added declaration.

Comment: Btw `timer.scheduleRepeating(deadline: startTime(interval, now: now), repeating: interval!)` would work too.

Comment: Apparently there is no `Double.multiplied(by:)` method, otherwise that code would compile.

Answer (score 1):

Used interval * to replace multiplied(by:

```
    timer.scheduleRepeating(deadline: startTime(interval, now: now), interval: DispatchTimeInterval.nanoseconds(Int(interval * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))))
```